# Server.mappath (NOT) and domain folder outside the webspace

Tags: asp-classic, filepath, server.mappath

It is possible to connect to a MS-Access mdb that is sitting outside of IIS on a regular domain folder? We have a company-wide share (S:) and am trying to do a quick a dirty connection to an mdb in a folder there. like this:

```
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
odbcName = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & server.mappath("S:/share/Workspaces/IntranetData/Departments/IT/public_datasignatures.mdb") & ";"
conn.mode=3
conn.open odbcName,"",""
```

what would I use instead of server.mappath for physical locations?

Thanks for any help,
JM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Server.MapPath` since you have a full path; but:

- I imagine that s: will only be a mapped drive from a user login, not from IIS
- you'll need to reference the full network path, e.g. \servername\share...
- the account that IIS runs under will need network access to that share on the other server

You would be far better served (no pun intended!) importing that .mdb into SQL Server and connecting to it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to map at all, since you already know the exact location, so:

`odbcName = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=S:/share/Workspaces/IntranetData/Departments/IT/public_datasignatures.mdb;"`